# How to fix empty folders in an NFS export?

Tags: mount, nfs

Here's my `/etc/mtab` file on the server (the important parts):

```
/dev/sda1 / ext4 rw,errors=remount-ro 0 0
/dev/sda5 /home ext4 rw 0 0
/dev/sdb1 /data ext3 rw 0 0
/dev/sdc /data/video ext3 rw 0 0
```

Here's my `/etc/exports`:

```
/data 192.168.2.0/24(rw,insecure,all_squash,anonuid=1000,anongid=100)
```

The problem is: within `/data` is a music and books folder, as well as video..

when i mount the NFS drive on any other machine, I can see the contents of `/data/books` and `/data/music` but `/data/video` is empty.

I can't seem to figure out why.

Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42131/how-to-properly-export-and-import-nfs-shares-that-have-subdirectories-as-mount-p.

Comment: should it not be `/dev/sdc1 /data/video ext3 rw 0 0` (mind the sdc1)

Answer (score 4):

Any device mounted separately needs to have its own export entry. So if you have an export `/exp` and mount some devices on `/exp/mnt1`, `/exp/mnt2`, etc., then each of those directories need to be exported, and mounted on the client. So your `/etc/exports` will look like:

```
/data 192.168.2.0/24(rw,insecure,all_squash,anonuid=1000,anongid=100)
/data/video 192.168.2.0/24(rw,insecure,all_squash,anonuid=1000,anongid=100)
```

And you will have to add entries to the client `/etc/fstab` for both exports. 
There's also a typo in your `/etc/fstab`, where `/dev/sdc` should be `/dev/sdc1` (or whatever the partition actually is). Have a look at this [Unix & Linux question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42131/how-to-properly-export-and-import-nfs-shares-that-have-subdirectories-as-mount-p) for more information.